# Is a complete Android device lab necessary for a photo uploading and remote CRUD app?

Tags: android

I'm an Android newbie who's past the basics. I've been reading some material on high performance Android apps and the suggestions so far are that I should have a collection of Android devices to test on. The app I want to write will do only two things: one, pick photos from the file system, crop/resize them and then send them to a remote server and, two, provide a dashboard for CRUD actions against a remote API.

Since I don't yet have the experience developing and testing Android apps, I'm not in a position to accurately estimate whether a collection of Android devices will be a prudent investment. So far, I've been using Genymotion for the emulation and neither can I estimate if it's enough. What I do know, though, is that not all apps are the same -- some apps are more feature rich and more sophisticated than others and thus will require more comprehensive testing across a greater number of devices while others don't.

So, is a complete Android device lab necessary for a photo uploading and remote CRUD app?

Comment: How much testing you need depends a lot on the requirements of the project and the level of quality you want to achieve. This question is difficult to answer like that. I would just make sure you test on some Samsung devices though, as many times they have different bugs than devices with stock Android like Nexuses. Give a go to the stock emulator too.

Comment: I imagine the requirements are actually quite simple. With an app like this, then the photo cropping/resizing/uploading should be smooth and snappy and the API calls should be as fast as possible. What else have I missed?

Comment: "is a complete Android device lab necessary for a photo uploading and remote CRUD app?" -- what does "complete" mean?

Comment: Don't mind the semantics. What I mean is, for my app, picking files from the filesystem is pretty standard and elementary Android. So is making remote API calls. Since all that functionality is quite simple, will I need a complete range of Android devices to do the testing?